# replace <a> with <button> for one instance using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that is automatically generated and would like to replace  with .

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
 var $button = $('<button />');
 $('li:first-child a').replaceWith($button);
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I only want to change link 2 to a button.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why not just format the a tag to look like a button? Whatever a button on your site looks like

Comment: Nevermind, I just found the answer in another post.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Does the button not appear? What exactly doesn't work for you. Yes there is an upvoted answer but it's pretty much exactly what you have so some details would be helpful.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lqgwdhc/1/

Comment: @scrappedcola The *upvoted answer* is far from being the same as what he has... It misses some explanation though.

Comment: [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon the only new item the upvoted answer provides is that it takes the html from the existing link and add it to the button. It's not vastly different and if that was what the OP was after then they should have stated what was missing/wrong.

Comment: @scrappedcola first of, using a variable will not clone the object. So in the end, the first link will be removed and there will be only 1 button on the page. Second, the function use `$(this).html()`, so the button will have the same text as the link.

Comment: @scrappedcola also, I kinda missed the `:first-child` part, so you can ignore my first comment. Anyway, it is still better than what op has.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write function inside `replaceWith` that would do the magic:

```js
$('li:first-child a').replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<button />", {
    html: $(this).html()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its working:

```
 $('ul li:nth-child(2)').html('<button />');
```